# Assembly Multiplication with Limited Instructions (Modified MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, bitwise-operators

We built a custom assembler based on MIPS design. The main challenge is that we only have these instructions to work with: add, nand, lw, sw, beq, jalr, noop, halt.

With these we must multiply 2 numbers, then stored in a specific register (the example given is 29562 * 11834).

The issue we have is that everything we found uses sll or the like to shift bits in order to do the multiplication. And no, we cannot just use the "add" instruction over and over, since it must run in less than 1000 instructions.

Any bit-manipulation algorithms or other ideas with those instructions would be very helpful.

Comment: You realize you can use `add` for `sll`, right? And it's not linear time.

Comment: @Jester what do you mean by that? As in it could replace sll in functionality?

Comment: Yes. `add $t0, $t0, $t0` is of course same as `sll $t0, $t0, 1`.

Comment: a word in mips is 32 bits yes? How is that different?

Comment: a + a = 2 * a = a << 1;  ... b = a + a;  b = b + b = a << 2;  then do multiplication for say three or four bit numbers with pencil and paper and see that although just the same as decimal there is a shortcut.   nand is your and.  add is your shift.   done.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is the use of nand. When we left shift by 1, then nand it, it is just 0.

Comment: [From `nand` you can build everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic#Making_other_gates_by_using_NAND_gates). You did it wrong. What does "nand it" even mean.

Comment: Alright, so we make a beq loop to make the AND gate from the NAND instruction. We implemented that, but what can we do to figure out the relationship with left shifting and AND to get multiplication?

Comment: Start with an algorithm in C, mask (and) shift and add are all that is required.  Once you have it working in C then (simply, grin) code it in assembly.

Comment: @Jester The concept "from nand you can build everything" is only half the truth: If you have one bit per register (or you use only one bit per register) this is absolutely true. However using only "bitwise" operations (e.g. bitwise nand) you cannot do very much when using registers with more than one bit width. (However: nand, beq, lw and sw should be enough to do everything!)